# Updating value under specified column in the file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a text file in the following format:

```
# this is the comment
# And this is also a comment

FIELD1
COL11      COL12      COL13      
5           10          15       

FIELD2
COL21      COL22       COL23      COL24     
12           34         45          55

.......
.......
```

I want to update the value mentioned under COL24 (55) to some other value lets say 100.I can read that value using the following shell:

```
grep -A 1 COL21 /Dir/To/File/filename.txt  | sed -e '1 d' | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}
```

But how do we update the value ?

Comment: Is it always 4th column or can vary?

Comment: No, its always 4th column;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '/FIELD2/{r=NR+2} NR==r{$4=100} 1' OFS='\t' file
```

Comment: this is updating the value. but it is also updating fourth column of second line of the file. The output after running the command is :

# this is the comment
#       And     this    **100**     also    a       comment

FIELD1
COL11      COL12      COL13
5           10          15

FIELD2
COL21      COL22       COL23      COL24
12      34      45      **100**

.......
.......